# Is there any free, small, fast, thing for compiling C# .net 3.5 console apps on windows?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

Is there any free, small, fast, thing for compiling C# .net 3.5 console apps on Windows?  I want something to write c# windows consol apps using ffmpeg (using tao framework) on my home eee pc; can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this:
http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/

Answer (score 19):

Sure, ***csc.exe***

It's the official C# compiler, included with the .net installation, and what Visual Studio uses--but you can easily use it from the command line:

[Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

---

Update: another useful tool, which might be more of what you're after (and is still supported/maintained) is [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).  It's main purpose is for building LINQ statements, but it's fully capable of executing regular .NET code as well.

Comment: Included with .NET, which you can download and install (for free) from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992

Answer (score 8):

You can also use mono, it's a free, small and fast thing. It's open source and can be downloaded from www.mono-project.com

Answer (score 3):

I think csc.exe is the first option.

But for ide, debug and edit you can use ShapDevelop. http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/